# Maven clean - delete target folder what leads to unresolved imports

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

I am generating classes from WSDL using maven apache.cxf plugin. It will generate classes to "target" folder.
I am using these classes in my project (import generated.wsdlclass...) but when I run **mvn clean install** it will delete target folder completely which leads to unresolved imports in my project and maven will crash regenerating target folder. It complains I have errors in my project (because it deletes my generated classes I was using)... 
How should I solve this problem ? At first of all I thought maybe I should tell maven don't delete my generated classes in my target folder but I've read it's against maven policy and it is not good practice to do it. What's the best approach to solve this problem ? How should I generate classes from wsdl and how should I use them ?
Thanks

Comment: Please show your pom file cause it sounds you done some thing wrong?

Comment: It's ok, I had everything ok. I am just not get used to that maven tab in Intellij Idea. I hit clean which deletes my target folder and then hit package which tried to compile my project and fails (I thought it's the same as mvn clean install). I didn't realize there is "hidden" option generate sources and update folders. As Roland mentioned generate-sources phase must happen before compile. mvn clean install from command line works and it also works from Intellij I just left out that option "generate sources" because it's on a very bad spot didn't see it until now... Anyway thanks for help :)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VCLY.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes must be generated before the `compile` phase. To achieve that bind the maven-plugin to the `generate-sources` phase.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>...</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

See also the [Maven Lifecycle Reference](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Lifecycle_Reference).